# how to increment 5 bit numbers in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am working on implementing a counter component to my vending machine where a user can select 2 items candy 5 cent gum is 10 cent and came across some difficulties with how do I increment a number by 5 or 10 depending on what the user select when I run my code I am getting a runtime error when trying to simulate it also the user can only put up to 30 cent into the machine.

the counter component only keeps track of the amount of nickels or dimes put into the machine such as: 5 cent then another 10 cent the counter will increment to  15

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;  

entity count is port(clk,reset,nickel,dime:in std_logic;
            totalAmt:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));

end count;

architecture beh of count is
signal sum:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal tmp1: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0101";
signal tmp2: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1010";
signal tally: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal grantot: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
process(clk,reset,nickel,dime,sum)
begin
sum <= "0000";
tally <= "0000";
if (reset = '1') then sum <= "0000";

elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then

elsif(nickel = '1') then sum <=  tmp1;  -- when nickel or dime is set to one it increments the sume amount by 5 or 10 in binary

elsif(dime = '1') then tally <= tmp2;


end if;

end process;
grantot <= sum + tally;
--if sum >= "11110" then
--report "error";

--else
totalAmt <= grantot;
--end if; 
end;
```

Comment: Please edit the question with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the math directly on `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` signals. You need to declare some sort of math type - I would recommend the type `UNSIGNED`, which is included in the `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL` package that you already include in your code.

You can declare it as follows:

`signal  sum : UNSIGNED(4 downto 0) := to_unsigned(<your_number>, <signal_width>;`

Where `<signal_width>` would be 5, since you're using 5 bit numbers.

Keep in mind that you'll need to resize your signals after an addition, since the result of an addition of two numbers is wider than the original operands. You do that as follows:

`sum <= resize( tmp1 + tmp2, <signal_width>)`

Where `<signal_width>` will be 5, as that's how wide you declared `sum`. If you don't do the resize, you will likely get an error saying that your target signal isn't wide enough.

Comment: The initial premise for your answer falls short. `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;` provides a Synopsys package that treats type std_logic_vector as type unsigned, providing arithmetic functions as would IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned (-2008). These nor package numeric_std require resizing after addition. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the section **Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions**.

Comment: @JAYLEWIS <you_number> is a number, 1, 2, 3,... that you want to initialize the signal to.

Comment: @user1155120, the package `numeric_std`'s signed and unsigned types do in fact require resizing after addition, at least before 2008, which many do not use. Try to simulate it in Vivado - it won't work. I'm not sure how you can claim that the premise for my answer falls short, when it holds the exact information the poster needs, even if he didn't ask it well. All you're doing is recommending a different package.

Comment: Resizing for what purpose? The result is the length of the operand with the greatest length. Your mistaken, there is no difference in operation between pre visions prior to -2008. The IEEE packages are functionally consistent.

Comment: If you add two 5-bit unsigned numbers, then their sum will be 6 bits to account for overflow. For example, if you're adding 31 + 31 = 62, then you can't represent that with 5 bits. The `numeric_std` package takes this into account, so if you want to store the result in a five bit register, you will have to resize it first. Try it yourself. You are likely correct right that 2008 behaves the same; I don't use it.